# Access function from .Android level in shared level

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How would i go about accessing a function from a class who sits in the ".Android" level in my shared project level?

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJwNE.png)

As you can see on the picture. I want to access the function called "OpenLink" who sits in the "GetData.cs" class in my "TabPage2.xaml.cs" class who sits in the higher level (outside the .Android structure).

The reason i have to do this is because i want to use this code to open a link

```
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(arg);
            var linkIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            StartActivity(linkIntent);
```

StartAcitivity is not valid if it is not placed in the ".Android" level.
Any help with this? Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can open a link directly from Xamarin Forms using

```
Device.OpenUri();
```

However, if you really need to access an Android function from shared code, you can either use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) or [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to do it